# XML Parsing -Python

Tags: python, xml

Here is URL. I cant get a root to return at all;   trying to get back vessel_name fields

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url='http://corpslocks.usace.army.mil/lpwb/xml.lockqueue?in_river=mI&in_lock=26'

page=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

tree = ET.ElementTree(page)
root=tree.getroot()
root.tag
root.attrib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `urlopen()` returns the page as a stream of bytes which requires to decode it before parsing. After decoding you can directly create `Element Tree` from string. You can extract each vessel_name with that code:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url='http://corpslocks.usace.army.mil/lpwb/xml.lockqueue?in_river=mI&in_lock=26'

page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
charset=page.info().get_content_charset() # check what charset is used
content=page.read().decode(charset) # decode reponse
tree = ET.fromstring(content)

for row in tree:
    print(row[0].text)
```

Comment: Truly appreciate your assistance.    The translation from Coursera to 'real-world' has been difficult for me with Python.   Your assistance means a great deal to me

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote the answer if it was that what you expected.